# Printing makes superscript minus signs disappear when using scrartcl

Tags: superscripts, printing

When I have minus signs in superscripts, they disappear when printing out the pdf that pdflatex produces, but only when using the `scrartcl` documentclass, not `article`. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\(x^{-1}\)
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\(x^{-1}\)
\end{document}
```

both produce a pdf which looks like this:

[image: x with superscript minus one]

However, when I print out the pdf generated from the first one, I get

[image: printed x with superscript -1]

whereas printing out the pdf generated from the second one gives

[image: printed x with superscript 1]

How can I fix this?

## Edit

You are all correct in suggesting that this is being caused by the different default font sizes in `article` and `scrartcl`. This reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\(x^{-1}\)
\end{document}
```

While this does not:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\(x^{-1}\)
\end{document}
```

This is the log file for the 11pt `article` case:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.3.15)  16 APR 2017 10:29
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\input mcve.ltx
(./mcve.ltx (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (./mcve.aux)
\openout1 = `mcve.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10.95> on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 4.
 [1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./mcve.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 220 strings out of 493013
 2322 string characters out of 6139317
 53632 words of memory out of 5000000
 3844 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 6379 words of font info for 23 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 21i,4n,19p,117b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
 </home/will
/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/cmr10.657pk> </usr/share/texmf-di
st/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr8.pk> </home/will/.texlive/texmf-var/fon
ts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/cmsy8.600pk> </home/will/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljf
our/public/cm/cmmi10.657pk>
Output written on mcve.pdf (1 page, 2342 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 28 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 20 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

As for my system and the printer itself, I'm running Arch Linux and printing via CUPS. The printer is an HP OfficeJet Pro 8600. CUPS lists the driver as `HP Officejet Pro 8600 hpijs, 3.16.11 (color, 2-sided printing)`, which I got by installing the `hplip` package. There do not appear to be any font rendering options in the print dialog or in CUPS.

Comment: Show also the log file so that we can see the texsystem, the version and the fonts used.

Comment: can't replicate here on a linux system using tex live 2016.

Comment: Uh! Your TeX system is using bitmap fonts! Please, do a full install of TeX Live.

Comment: @egreg Aha! I had installed the package `texlive-core` on my system, but apparently that does not include all the fonts that I need. I replaced it with `texlive-most` and now the problem is resolved. If you make your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your log file is the most significant:

```
 </home/will
/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/cmr10.657pk> </usr/share/texmf-di
st/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr8.pk> </home/will/.texlive/texmf-var/fon
ts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/cmsy8.600pk> </home/will/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljf
our/public/cm/cmmi10.657pk>
```

It basically means you are using bitmap fonts for your PDF output. Depending on the PDF viewer this can cause apparent disparition of symbols that would show up at different magnifications.

Install a full TeX Live, so Type1 (outline) fonts will be used, which have hints for display at various magnifications/resolutions.